# $(shell ...) in Makefile can run before preceding lines in same recipe

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

I am using Makefile PHONY for CI. But I found the order of commands under the target is not run  in sequential, more specifically, the command inside $() seems to run ahead of time. Is this some default behavior of Makefile?

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

.PHONY: test
test:
    cat input-test.txt > output.txt
    @[ $(shell wc -l < output-test.txt) -eq $(shell wc -l < input-test.txt) ]
    rm output-test.txt
```

by running `make test` it shows

```sh
/bin/sh: output-test.txt: No such file or directory
cat input-test.txt > output.txt
/bin/sh: line 0: [: -eq: unary operator expected
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

Comment: Indeed, any `make` syntax gets evaluated when `make` parses the `Makefile`, before it even knows which recipes it is going to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make commands like `$(shell ...)` are executed before any of your actual recipes are run.  Therefore, the line

```
cat input-test.txt > output.txt
```

hasn't been run yet.

If you want that command to be run in the proper order, replace it with

```
@[ $$(wc -l < output-test.txt) -eq $$(wc -l < input-test.txt) ]
```

Comment: More specifically, the entire recipe is completely expanded (including all variables and functions) before any command in the recipe is executed.  Also, in your example you need to escape the `$` in `$(wc ...)`: it should be `$$(wc ...)`